# getting error while integrating flajaxian.FileUploader

Tags: .net, file-upload, flajaxian

I am facing problem with the control flajaxian.FileUploader i.e. after downloading the dll file while implement i am getting following error message i.e.

Request for the permission of the type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c56193e089' failed.

Help me to sort out this problem, so that i can implement the control for multiple image file uploader, below is my code.

```
      <Adapters>

    <fjx:FileSaverAdapter Runat="server" FolderName="UploadFolder" />

        </Adapters>
```

Not mentioned any thing in web config for this control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the site from where i downloaded they have given the dll which is not updated, hence instead of downloding the dll download the source code and compile once. It will work. I did it and it working fine.